# Where can I find Folder Syncing to a Web Server a la Dropbox?

Tags: web-services, synchronization, dropbox

I saw this somewhere, but I can't remember where.

Where can I find, for Mac OS X, a system that automatically syncs a folder to your web server, sort of like Dropbox does? The idea being that I can edit code on my computer, and it automatically updates it on the server.

It seems so simple, but I can't for the life of me find the service.

Thanks!

Comment: Not really programming related.

Comment: @Ben S: Why? A question about Visual Studio is programming related, but the one about code mirroring is not?

Answer (score 1):

[rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync) seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox's web interface IS a web server.  But I presume you mean your own server.

So put **dropbox** on your own server, and have the server serve the dropbox files.